# How do you step in/out/over the Xcode debugger via Applescript?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, applescript

I am developing an iOS application. I spend a lot of time in the simulator and it would be really helpful if I didn't have to switch back to Xcode to access the debuggers step in/out/over/continue controls. Is there a way to do this without Xcode being the application with focus?

(I know about the mini debugger, but that doesn't have step controls on it, and I'd prefer keyboard shortcuts.)

I thought it might be scriptable, but it didn't seem like there was a hook for it in the Xcode AppleScript dictionary. (I'm definitely not an AppleScript expert by any means, though.)

I don't think GUI scripting would get me what I want since it would switch to Xcode step and switch back. But it might be better than nothing if it was fast enough.

Is there a way to send a keyboard command to an application that's doesn't have focus?

Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty certain that even using UI interface scripting via Applescript (if the controls you wanted were accessible in Xcode), it would switch between your app and Xcode thanks to the "tell application Xcode" call.

Comment: Have a look at the System Events dictionary in Applescript - I think it allows keystroke programming which may be helpful to you.

Comment: Adding the keyword `activate` causes the target application for the `tell` block to be brought to the front, otherwise the order remains the same despite the commands sent to it. I do not know, however, if that behavior would be same in the case of UI scripting.

Comment: Use a second monitor for Xcode, tell it via Applescript to step, then tell the iOS Simulator something to bring it back in front, both in the same script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you can do this without using UI scripting, which I try to avoid. (See Clark's answer if you want to do that, though.) This appears to be the case for Xcode 3 and Xcode 4.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

To see Xcode's scripting support, launch Script Editor, find the Open Dictionary command, and select Xcode.

Comment: I did mention in the original post that I checked the dictionary and couldn't find anything about stepping through the debugger, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned use UI scripting. So to step through code in the debugger you'd use this in Applescript:

```
tell application "XCode"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "i" using {command down, shift down}
end tell
```

And this in Appscript:

```
app(u'Xcode').activate()
app(u'System Events').keystroke(u'i', using=[k.command_down, k.shift_down])
```

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't let me remain in the simulator without having it switch back, etc. I was hoping for a more supported way to do this. Thanks for your suggestion, though.